# Add value to the row (tr) tag while using jquery DataTables plugin

Tags: jquery, html, json, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables plugin to populates two tables with JSON data. What I want is except from the columns to also have value set for the rows (which will actually be the whole JSON). Is there a way to automatically do this?

Example: The table is constructed in this way:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
  "columns": [
    { "data": "Name", "title": "Name"},
    { "data": "Name", "title": "Name"}
  ]
});
```

Is filled in this way:

```
$.getJSON(url, null, function( json ) {
  var table = $('#table').DataTable();
  table.rows.add(json).draw();
}
```

Example of wanted output:

```
<tr value="WHOLE JSON">
  <td value="JSON PART">JSON PART</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you could prepare live example of what you have done so far and what you want to achieve, it would let us better understand your question and provide proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) function?

you can use it to something like this

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Name", "title": "Name"},
        { "data": "Name", "title": "Name"}
    ],
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        $(row).attr('data-value', data);
    }
});
```